# Retrieving a model based on combined value of two columns?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need a relatively simple statement where I sort my model based on two columns, hours and minutes, on said model.

The following works

```
$recipes->where('minutes','>', $minTime)->get();
```

But what I really want to do is

```
$recipes->where('hours * 60 + minutes','<', $minTime)->get();
```

Sadly this syntax is not available, I have been messing around with a couple of other solutions but I have been unable to solve it.

I was hoping for some directions as I have gotten stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Laravel uses bindings in where statements and escapes them. To do calculations and such, use `whereRaw`:

```
$recipes->whereRaw('hours * 60 + minutes < '.$minTime)->get();
```

However now your query is vulnerable to SQL injection to avoid that create a binding manually:

```
$recipes->whereRaw('hours * 60 + minutes < ?', [$minTime])->get();
```

---

Instead of `whereRaw` you can also use `DB::raw()` inside the normal `where` function:

```
$recipes->where(DB::raw('hours * 60 + minutes'),'<', $minTime)->get();
```

This tells Laravel to not escape this part of the query.